# SSH: StrictHostKeyChecking is set to no, but prompt still appears

Tags: server, ssh

I am trying to set up auto deploy from my script, which is ran through Travis CI, so I need to SSH into my server without any prompts.

My deploy script looks like this:

```
ssh ubuntu@123.123.123 -i ./travis/id_rsa <<EOF
  echo "PRINT SOMETHINGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG"
EOF
```

This works locally because I have already SSHed to the server before and said "yes" to all the prompts.

On my server (IP address: 123.123.123), I have a user `ubuntu`.

I tried setting `StrictHostKeyChecking no` in my `/home/ubuntu/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

However, even with this setting it keeps asking me for my fingerprint.

```
The authenticity of host '123.123.123 (123.123.123)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 87:a8:8a:50:9c:a9:87:3e:c5:17:6d:b0:f1:28:7e:d3.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

How would I stop it from asking?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me: Did you add/edit the `.ssh/confg` file on the _server_?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I did that on the server (`123.123.123` as the `ubuntu` user)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [docs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/ssh_config.5.html):

> **StrictHostKeyChecking**
>
> [...] If this flag is set to “no” or “off”, ssh will automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts files and allow connections to hosts
>   with changed hostkeys to proceed, subject to some restrictions. [...]

You need to add that setting ***on the client***, either by putting the lines

```
# for all hosts
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

or

```
# for a particular host
Host 123.123.123.123
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

into your ***local*** `~/.ssh/config`.

You can also supply the option directly in your `ssh` command (thus overwriting any settings in the config file):

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@123.123.123.123 -i ./travis/id_rsa
```

The host key tells the *client* that the target host is actually the host it pretends to be. In theory you could call the server's admin and ask him (on the phone or something) to tell you the output of `ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub` and then compare that string with the fingerprint shown on your client. If they match, then you are safe and can add that key to your `known_hosts` file. With `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` you simply tell *the client* to just *believe/trust* the target machine and accept its key.

Comment: Oh!!! So I have to add that config to the server I'm SSHing from, not to. Thanks!!

Comment: @Edmund Exactly. I've amended my answer.

Comment: @Edmund given the motivation (auto-deploy), `accept-new` would be a more secure option than plain `no`.